# failed to solve: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token":

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I got this error when running the 'docker compose up' command. Below is how it looks.

```
$ docker compose up -d
```

```
[+] Building 12.1s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                        docker:default
 => [todo-app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                      0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.25kB                                                                             0.1s
 => ERROR [todo-app] resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                       11.7s
 => [todo-app auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                          0.0s
------
 > [todo-app] resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1:
------
failed to solve: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io on 172.23.96.1:53: read udp 172.23.102.243:35023->172.23.96.1:53: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`(s)?